# Contrasting EnyoJS Components, Kinds, Controls, Collections, Models

Tags: enyo

Edit: A simpler phrasing of this question would be...

**Can't I build a full fledged enyo app with readable code while only using Controls to take the place of Components, Kinds, Models, and Collections?**

..

I'm learning EnyoJS and I have yet to find a clear comparison between Components, Kinds, Controls, Collections, and Models.

I understand that for example a Control is a Component that by convention refers to a visible DOM element that the user interacts with directly...but so many of these differences among the aforementioned types seem to be by convention rather than enforced by the framework. It seems that any given idea can be expressed as a Component or a Collection or a Model or...

Can you clearly explain the API differences between these types?

Can you show how certain functionality is truly missing from any one of them but present in another?

Answer (score 1):

Wow. That's a big question.

With regards to controls and components, it's not just convention that differentiates the two. Controls are an Enyo Kind that inherits from the Component Enyo Kind. Controls actually contain methods and properties (specifically for dealing with the DOM) that just don't exist in Components. They're not interchangeable.

The documentation on the Enyo web site does a very good job of explaining the difference between Kinds, Components and Controls.

http://enyojs.com/docs/2.4.0/

There's also the API reference, which breaks out for you the various properties, so you can see for yourself all of the properties that exist (and don't exist) in Kinds, Components and Controls.

http://enyojs.com/docs/2.4.0/api.html#enyo.Control

And finally, since Enyo is open source, you can look at the actual source code to see the differences.

Collections and Models are fairly new to Enyo, starting with Enyo 2.4. Their job is to hold data (A Collection is a group of one or more instances of a Model). Models usually contain JavaScript or Enyo Objects, not Components or Controls.

Components make up the skeleton of your app, Controls are the UI for your app and Models contain the data for your app.

Comment: To be more specific, I could ask the question "Can't I build a full fledged enyo app with readable code while only using Controls to take the place of Components, Kinds, Models, and Collections?"

Comment: What do you mean by "full fledged"? But, yes, you can build an app using JavaScript and a subset of what Enyo offers. You'd probably end up replacing functionality readily available in Enyo with code you wrote yourself or code from one or more other libraries. It probably won't be as coherent or readable as an app written using Enyo in the way it was designed to be used, however.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding a bit on Art's answer: You can certainly build a fully functional and maintainable app without Models and Collections. Those kinds help with the data binding infrastructure in version 2.4. If you don't wish to use those features, you can build on version 2.2 and only use Controls and its subkinds (e.g. enyo.Input).

Regarding Components, you could easily build an enyo without creating your own Component but you can't avoid *using* them because it's part of Control's prototype hierarchy. As Art said, the difference between Component and Control is more than convention. The Component kind facilitates the composition of instances of components. Control extends that to support rendering into the DOM and its containment hierarchy. See [post from my Enyo Daily series](http://blog.technisode.com/post/7941076324/enyo-daily-3-ownership) for some (slightly dated) details.

More concretely, if you don't need to render anything into the DOM but you want to encapsulate some logic into something module-like, use Component. If you need a DOM node, use Control or one of its derivatives.